# Font not viewing in Xcode 6 - what I'm I doing wrong

Tags: xcode

I'm using xcode 6 as I want to use custom fonts without coding - this I believe is a new feature of xcode 6, I have added the font to the project and opened the font in fontbook - the font appears in the interface builder and renders But when I run the app on my ipad to test it doesn't show the font or even pick up the font size set!

I have a feeling I'm just missing something very simple - any ideas guys?

I have screen grabs of the app in xcode and running to illustrate this but as this is my first question i'm unable to post them.

Comment: I've sorted this issue - the text view was set to Attributed, by changing it to Plain this has made the font view correctly.

Comment: It probably is a bug. You can recreate it using the following procedure: 

After having imported the custom fonts (ttf/otf format) to your project, try to apply a custom font in a UILabel. 
In **plain** text you can't set a custom font, because it reverts to the default. 

Change text to **attributed**, mark the text, select the font and you can see the font face change in the interface builder. However it doesn't change in the Simulator/iOS Device.

In order for it to work in the device, you have to revert the text to **plain**.

Comment: Have you sorted this ? I am still seeing this behaviour in xcode 6 gm